# How to retain the TextBox control text value across pages in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a test.ascx.page, which contains a textbox control.

the value that control is set by another page test2.aspx.cs.

I want to retain the value of textbox(txtNo) at user session level and across pages , so currently i am doing it by defining TextBox as static control.

```
test.ascx.cs

        public static TextBox txtNo
        public TextBox no
        {
            set { txtNo= value; }
            get { return txtURN; }
        }


test2.aspx.cs
//txtNumber is a texbox control
test.no= txtNumber;
txtNumber.text= test2.no.Text;
```

As static varaibles have thread safety issues, are there any alternatives of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: static is not a solution is web based applications

Comment: @EhsanSajjad .. yep, any idea how we can do it with Session?i want to retain value in a TextBox txtNo.

Comment: @SunilDhami check my answer...

Comment: @DiegoS  Is myTextBox a control?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain information between pages you are looking for  [ASP .NET State Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx). You can choose between different flavours:

- View state
- Control state
- Hidden fields
- Cookies
- Query strings
- Application state
- Session state
- Profile Properties

I will explain the most used approaches:

1. Use [Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) to save an Object with properties, Session variable is available in every page for the same user during his login period on your site. So in your test.ascx you save the variable like:

`Session["myTextBox"]= myTextbox;`

which will be available in the methods of your test2.aspx page with:

`Object txtBox1 = Session["myTextBox"];`

2. Use [Query String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass the data to the next page via the URL like:

`~/test2.aspx?textNo=4&textName=someName`

which will be available in the Page_Load method of test2.aspx page with:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int textNo = Request.QueryString["textNo"];
       string textName = Request.QueryString["textName"];
    }
```

Comment: is  myTextBox  a control?

Comment: @SunilDhami it should not be a control. It can be a Class or a Value, if you need to store only the textno you can save that value (replace Textbox with the number in the example). Tell me what you need to store and i'll update my answer

Comment: I am trying to set the TextBox txtNo of ascx file on test.no= txtNumber of aspx.cs file.

Comment: Then in your ascx file do: Session["txtNo"] = Textbox.texNo. And in your aspx file do: test.no = Session["txtNo"]